# Ethernet not working in ubuntu 20.04 in HP 15q de 0017 tu laptop

Tags: 20.04, ethernet, hp

My wifi and ethernet were working good till yesterday. But after the ubuntu update to 20.04 , both stopped working. My wifi modem is fine as I am able to access it by my mobile phone.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `dpkg -l | grep linux` command.

Comment: I donot have any internet access in my laptop as both wired and wireless network are not working and askubuntu is not letting me attach screenshots as I donot have 10 reputation points.

Comment: @SatishBabuBonu Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. You may upload it to any img sharing site and include only link here. If you can copy the text through USB then edit question, it will be the best.

Answer (score 0):

1. full poweroff,
2. remove battery,
3. press power button for 5 sec,
4. put it all together,
5. turn on laptop

This will clear bios misinformation.

Worked twice on my laptop after SO upgrade

Comment: Battery is not removable type.